# rmdir in PHP not working on an empty directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove a directory with PHP.

I unlink/remove all files/subdirs from the inside out and finally call rmdir on the now empty top directory. Everything goes according to plan until the last call to rmdir. PHP warns that the directory is NOT emtpy and refuses to remove it. But when I look at the directory in the explorer it is empty, after all.

I also tried a well known recursive function with the same result.

The operating system is Windows 7 with Xampp and there are no access restrictions for any of the elements in question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a wild quess.....hidden files?

Comment: can you check is there any hidden files/sub-folders where the name is start with dot `.something` ? Also, `rm -rf folder` should works in Linux bash (not quite sure is there something similar in Windows 7 ... )

Comment: @Baszz, ajreal: No, nothing like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
<?php
$handle = opendir($dirpath);
//do whatever you need
closedir($handle)
rmdir($dirpath);
?>
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thanks. But after looking at the PHP docs I don't understand why.

Comment: You were trying to remove a directory that php is still using.

Answer (score 1):

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
   if (is_dir($dir)) {
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $object) {
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
       }
     }
     reset($objects);
     rmdir($dir);
   }
}
```